# Not seeing files in VM shared folder

Tags: server, virtualbox, shared-folders

I created a shared folder in the VM shared folder in my Windows **C:\Users\sfox\documents\images with Access Full AutoMount Yes at /srv/tftp**

I put 2 or 3 files in the images folder on my windows pc but when I type `ls -lah /srv/tftp` on the VM I dont see any files.

I rebooted the VM after setting the shared folder and I use the following commands each time I start up the VM:

```
sudo apt install net-tools

sudo apt -y install tftp-server

sudo systemctl start tftpd-hpa
```

I also tried this step from another post but it did not work for me:

```
sudo apt install virtualbox-guest-utils
```

**E: Unable to locate package virtualbox-guest-utils**